# Transforming a mask preview into an actual image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, mask

I have a color photo that I'm editing in Photoshop this way:

1. select > color range > Midtones
2. Layer > New adjustment layer > Hue/Saturation

[image]

When I do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on the mask thumbnail in the layers panel this is what I see:

[image]

Now I want to save what I see in the mask preview as an image (in black and white). How can I achieve this?

Comment: With the process you are describing you are NOT working on a mask, you are on the image.

Comment: I edited my question, look at the mask above the layer

Comment: Frank I took the liberty to edit your question to make it more understandable, feel free to roll it back if you think it's not what you wanted to ask.

Comment: yes, it is more understandable !

Comment: Does resolution matter to you? Have you tried taking a simple screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your mask, create a new layer and fill the selection with white. Create a new color layer, paint it black and move it under the previous one. Perhaps the colors are reversed, I can't tell from your image; in that case just fill the layers with reversed colors.